# Calculation of coefficients of a function with respect to Legendre polynomials.

Tags: numerical-methods

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1   &x \in [-1,0],\\
+1   &x \in (0,1]\\
\end{cases}$$
the formula for calculation of coefficients in terms of Legendre polynomial $L_k(x)$  is:
$f_k= (2k+1)/2\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)L_k(x)dx$
can you please help me in calculating the answer of its coefficients which is:
$f_k= (-1)^k \frac {(4k+3)(2k)!}{2^{2k+1}(k+1)!k!}$

Comment: Yes it'll be solved by splitting  the integral otherwise we'll get zero answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\inf}c_n P_n(x)$ is the Legendre series for $f(x)$.
where $c_n = \frac{2n+1}{2} \int_{-1}^{+1}f(x)P_n(x)$ (this we get by multiplying first equation by $P_n(x)$ and then integrating from -1 to 1 and using the orthogonality property of Legendre polynomials.) 
Now since $f$ is an odd function, when $n$ is even $c_n=0$. and when $n$ is odd, i.e; $n=2k+1, c_{2k+1} = \frac{4k+3}{2} \int_{-1}^{+1}f(x)P_{2k+1}(x).$ which implies $c_{2k+1} = (4k+3) \int_{0}^{+1}f(x)P_{2k+1}(x)$ which implies $c_{2k+1} = (4k+3) \int_{0}^{+1}P_{2k+1}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Susmita for your response, would you please clear how f is an odd function here and cn=0 for even n?

Comment: When $x \in [0,1]$, $-x \in [-1,0]$. So, $f(-x)=-1$ when $x \in [0,1]$. similarly  $f(-x)=1$ when $x \in [-1,0]$. i.e; $f(-x) = -f(x)$. 
Now when $n$ is even,  $P_n(x)$ is an even function making the product $f(x)P_n(x)$ an odd function and therefore the integration will be zero.

Comment: bundle of Thanks Susmita for your valuable hints, i also revised the concepts of Fourier series for even and odd functions that make things more clearer to me. Also i know that $ P_2j (1) = 1$ also $ P_2j (0) = (−1)^j {(2j)!} /{2^{2j} (j!)^2}$